# how to find writes per second on mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, monitoring, benchmarking

Is there a mysql variable or monitoring that tells how many writes per second are being recorded ?

Can I use some variables values and compute to get the same result ?

Let's say I need to plot a graph dynamically of the same. What should i be doing ?

Im looking for command line options and not GUI based monitoring tools.

I have a mixed tokudb and innodb use case, so something non-storage engine specific would be better.

Comment: You may need to call `SHOW ENGINE` on each of these and collect metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi +
  Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) / Uptime
```

gives you "writes/sec" since startup.  This is from the point of view of the user issuing queries (such as INSERT).

Or did you want "rows written / sec"?

Or "disk writes / sec"?

The values for the above expression come from either `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` or the equivalent place in `information_schema`.

If you want "write in the last 10 minutes", then capture the counters 10 minutes ago and now.  The subtract to get the 'change' and finally divide.

There are several GUIs that will do that arithmetic and much more.  Consider MonYog ($$), MySQL Enterprise Monitor ($$$), cacti, etc.